# How to generate thumbnail (or Preview of first page) of office files (doc, xls etc.) using react.js (or javascript) at client side?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, office365, document

I am trying to generate the thumbnail (or Preview of first page) of office files (doc, xls etc.)  using react.js (or javascript) at the front end itself, but unable to get any feasible solution.

Same requirement was for the pdf files as well, that I've achieved using react-pdf package. Is there any way we can get the thumbnail for office files at the client side (front end) itself using react.js (or javascript)?

Comment: Thankyou for the response. Could you please explain the last sentence, i.e. how using SAAS or open apache office clone will help me to achieve my objective?

Comment: Also, can't we get the thumbnail without opening the file, e.g. if we are uploading the file, can we get the thumbnail (preview of first page) from uploaded file without opening it?

Comment: Creating thumbnails for Office formats requires components that are capable of loading them. Unless you are deploying such components as a local service for the client, it is more reliable to generate the thumbnails at the backend. For example, the LEADTOOLS JavaScript [Imaging Toolkit](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/display) uses a service that generates the images on the backend and provides them to the client through HTTP requests. You can find an online demo showing this [here](https://demo.leadtools.com/JavaScript/Thumbnails/) (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor)